# Airflow weekly schedule. Start date issue

Tags: airflow

I have a dag with a dummy task:

```
dag_1 = DAG(
    dag_id="my_dag",
    start_date=datetime(2023, 6, 15),
    schedule_interval="@weekly"
)

dummy_1 = DummyOperator(
    task_id="dummy_1",
    dag=dag_1
)

dummy_1
```

The problem is that I anticipate this dag to run once (catch-up) when activated since the schedule interval is weekly and the start_date is 15.06.2023 and today is 23.06.2023 (i.e. more than 7 day difference). However, the UI keeps giving me:

```
Next Run in 2 days

Data Interval:
Start: 2023-06-18
End: 2023-06-25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@weekly` schedule means `Run once a week at midnight (24:00) on Sunday` https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/dag-run.html

If you really want to run on the 7th day from the start date then you need to adjust your schedule interval a bit. For example, run on each Monday `0 0 * * 1`